# What will happen to this object

Tags: objective-c, ios, object

I have created one firstObject with the help of secondObject. Now I am released that secondObject what will happen to the firstObject. 
Here is my code.

```
SecondObject *secondObject = [[SecondObject alloc]init];
FirstObject *firstObject = [[FirstObject alloc]initWithSecondObject:secondObject];
[secondObject doSomethings];
[firstObject doSomeThings];
[secondObject release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `secondObject` has a reference to `firstObject` which it releases, nothing will happen to `firstObject`.

Answer (score 1):

If `firstObject` needs to keep a reference to `secondObject` beyond it's `initWithSecondObject:` method, it should retain `secondObject`. That will prevent `secondObject` from being deallocated even though you're releasing it in the code above. When you release an object, you're saying: "I'm done using this." But the object will only be deallocated if no other object is currently using it (as determined by the retain count, not that you should be looking at that).